# Using the wiremock Mappings in the spring boot application to mimic the external api behavious

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, mapping, wiremock

I have a use case where I need to test the external apis request for my application.

I have figured out the mappings part using the wiremock --proxy all and record mappings option but I am not able to use those wiremock mappings for my testing.
I need to know a way where I can host those mappings/files on a separate port and use them for request response.
Thanks

Comment: Can you create and provide a simple example of a URL that you ran through the proxy. Please provide the created mapping and any observations you have regarding the execution. Without more information we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Wiremock is to test or mock over the wire(http/https) data, it is similar to getting the response from HTTP request.

1) You need to setup wiremock server in your application and annotate test calss with springBootTest and runWith springRunner

2) you can define mocks/stubs as defined: [wiremock](http://new.wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/) [wiremock2](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/testing/wiremock-tutorial-request-matching-part-three/)

3) you can define regular experssions to map your methods and URL